# Unable to set "key" prop in element with .map()

Tags: reactjs, key

I am attempting to create an array of elements with .map() and am setting "key" to report._id, but i still get the same error message telling me that the prop is required and is missing. I am able to get all the other data from the array items that i need and am also able to console.log the report._id. The component is getting the report prop passed to it via Redirect from a different component. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const SearchResults = ({ report }) => {
  console.log(report.reports);

  return (
    <section className="container">
      <div>
        <h1>Search Results: </h1>
        {report.reports.map(report => (
          <div>
            <p key={report._id}>
              {console.log(report._id)}
              {report.projectName}, {report.contractor}, {report.projectManager}{" "}
            </p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

SearchResults.propTypes = {
  report: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  report: state.report
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SearchResults);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key needs to be on the highest level parent within the map:

```
{report.reports.map(report => (
  <div key={report._id}>
    <p>
      {console.log(report._id)}
      {report.projectName}, {report.contractor}, {report.projectManager}{" "}
    </p>
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: derp. I could have sworn i tried that...Thank You!!